# volvo c30 DMF or driveshaft bearing?

Tags: breakdown, drive-shaft, dual-mass-flywheel

I have a 2007 Volvo c30 D5 automatic(you can also drive it in manual)

Was driving to a friends and the car started making a grinding/metal on metal crunching noise.

Pulled over, couldn't see anything oblivious, carried on as friends was only 100 feet away.

Noise got worse so decided to tow my car home in neutral. car continued to make the noise even though it was tuned off and in neutral whilst being towed.

tried to tow the car to the garage last night as its only 10 mins away, started towing it, bits of metal started dropping out of the bottom of the engine bay.

At first I thought it was the dual mass flywheel failing as it was due to be replaced in the not so distant future(getting vibrations from it, etc) but the bits of metal i found on the road didn't look like parts off a DMF, they looked like they formed a circle similar to that of a driveshaft bearing, there was also quite a large ball bearing on the floor and the parts where covered in thick sticky oil not the usual thin flowing oil you put in the engine.

Here's the questions I have:

If the dual mass flywheel failed would it cause the noise to be made in neutral ? I'm not sure how they work but I thought they where only engaged when the car was in gear(same as the clutch)

If the driveshaft bearing has destroyed itself what other damage could I have done towing it ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd think this would have a DMF? I'm *pretty sure* it is only used on manual transmissions (not autos which can be shifted manually) ... I don't know for sure, I mean those crazy Swedes could be doing something funky, lol :o)

Comment: Iv'e checked a few parts sites and they list a DMF for my specific make and model, i too was unsure if it had one, I'll give volvo a call later and ask the question and update this post

Comment: I looked as well, but only see it listed for the manual version, not the automatic.

Comment: Same, Volvo said they don't think it has a dual mass flywheel but will speak to another dealership and email me back to confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a driveshaft joint or support bearing. If it failed completely and hit other things as you moved it then you will need to check brake lines, suspension components and any abs / brake wear warning wires - anything in the area of the broken part...

Comment: Could it of done any damage to the gearbox ? suspension/brake lines/abs are all relatively cheap to fix but because the gearbox is so complicated with it being an automatic and manual a second hand one is in excess of £4,500

Comment: To be sure you will need to test it - one of the problems of towing stuff now : lift&tow or trailer is often the safest solution.

Comment: The problem was a driveshaft that had disintegrated, Only replaced it last year and it had failed again already.

Comment: Question then : original parts quality or aftermarket cheaper ?

Comment: It was an original volvo part, After further inspection it looks like because iv'e lowered the car by a fair amount its putting more strain on the driveshafts due to the angle there going into the transmission at.